# How to create a list from two list and the element from those list alternatively

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm new in Haskell. I'm trying to Use recursion to write a function which, given two lists (they need to be of the same type), interleaves their elements (takes elements alternating between the first and the second list) . When there are no more elements in one of the lists, it stops and the result is the list achieved that far.

```
interChange :: [a] -> [b] ->[(a,b)]
interChange _ [] = []
interChange [] _ = []
interChange (x:xs) (y:ys) =  (x,y) : interChange xs ys
```

example of my output:

```
interChange [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
 [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

example of the needed output is:

```
interChange [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
[1,4,2,5,3,6]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `interChange` is the same as the Prelude's [`zip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip).

```
ghci> zip [1,2,3] ["wibble", "wobble", "wubble"]
[(1,"wibble"),(2,"wobble"),(3,"wubble")]
```

To write the function you specified, you in fact need a pair of lists *of the same type*. We're outputting a list of a particular type, so all of the elements going into that list must have that type as well.

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

You can implement this in a recursive fashion by passing around a `Bool` indicating which list you should take the next element from:

```
interleave = go True
    where go _ [] ys = ys
          go _ xs [] = xs
          go True (x:xs) ys = x : go False xs ys
          go False xs (y:ys) = y : go True xs ys
```

Evaluation ping-pongs between the last two clauses of `go` until either one of the input lists is empty, whereupon we just return the rest of the other one. (If you wanted it to behave more like `zip` you could have it truncate the output by returning `[]` instead of `xs` or `ys` in those cases.)

---

But I always recommend avoiding recursion to program at a higher level where possible. We can write this function as a pipeline:

1. Pair up the elements of the input lists using `zip`
2. Turn each tuple in the resulting list into a two-element list: `map (\(x, y) -> [x, y])`
3. Flatten the resulting list-of-lists using `concat`

So the code looks like this:

```
interleave xs ys = concat $ map (\(x, y) -> [x, y]) $ zip xs ys
```

I find this code much easier to understand than the recursive code, which requires you to reason about the flow of control - it's just a sequence of high-level instructions.

Incidentally, you can elide the intermediate `map` by dragging it into either the `concat` or the `zip`:

```
interleave xs ys = concatMap (\(x, y) -> [x, y]) $ zip xs ys
interleave xs ys = concat $ zipWith (\(x, y) -> [x, y]) xs ys
```

Comment: thank you so much for your replay,Your code is very good.However ,it dose't fulfill the last condition . When there are no more elements in one of the lists, it stops.your code give the output like this:[1,2,3,4] [6,7,8 ]= [1,6,2,7,3,8,4],but it should be  [1,6,2,7,3,8]

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out how to modify the code to fit the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

When `interChange` is called with two nonempty lists `(x:xs)` and `(y:ys)`, the output should be a list starting with `x` and then `y` and then more stuff. So you should write something like

```
interChange (x:xs) (y:ys) =  x : y : ...
```